# When writing a list to a .txt file with python, '\n' (backslash n) appear?

Tags: python

The result of my script is not as expected. I want to be able to write a word in each line in a .txt then read them into my script add something to them then output them to a PowerShell script.

The first thing I did not expect was the \n which I think is from the line shifting in the .txt. What is the best way to remove it?

The second thing is the first and the last [ ] which is less of a surprise but I still don't know how to filter it out. What would be the best way for that?

I'm new and self thought in python/coding so apologies if the code is a bit messi.

This is my code:

```
txt_list = []
new_txt_list = []
def StringDeleter(read_path):
    with open(read_path, 'r') as read_txt:
        for line in read_txt:
            line = str(line)
            txt_list.append(line)
    for input in txt_list:
        input1 = "-" + input
        input2 = "." + input
        input3 = "-[" + input + "]"
        input4 = ".[" + input + "]"
        input5 = "[" + input + "]"
        input6 = input
        new_txt_list.append(input1)
        new_txt_list.append(input2)
        new_txt_list.append(input3)
        new_txt_list.append(input4)
        new_txt_list.append(input5)
        new_txt_list.append(input6)
StringDeleter(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\123.txt")
with open(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Temp.PowerShell.ps1", "w") as temp_ps_script:
    temp_ps_script.write(str(new_txt_list))
```

This is the input file '123.txt':

```
String1
String2
```

This is the output file 'Temp.PowerShell.ps1':

```
['-String1\n', '.String1\n', '-[String1\n]', '.[String1\n]', '[String1\n]', 'String1\n', '-String2', '.String2', '-[String2]', '.[String2]', '[String2]', 'String2']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are on the end or start of the strings, you can use `strip()` but if you would just like to remove all \n's from the strings try this.

`line = line.replace('\n','')`

[replace()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace)

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. I will accept this answer when i can.